# JS Map returning issue

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I am using a mapping function to go through slide data and I want only the first 5 to return. However, slides is returning the first 5 slides and then 2 empty slides objects(since there are 7 slides. How do I prevent the last two from returning?

```
const slides = slideData.slides.map((slide, index) => {
  if( index < 5 ) {
    return slide;
  }
});
console.log(slides);
```

In addition, if I do something like..

```
let firstFive = [];
const slides = slideData.slides.map((slide, index) => {
  if( index < 5 ) {
    firstFive.push(slide)
  }
});
```

This works correctly, however I get a lint error saying `Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return`. What is the standard way of doing this?

Comment: What do you expect `slides` to contain in the second case?

Answer (score 3):

`map` always returns an array with the same number of elements as its input array.

Instead, consider using `filter` to only include the first first 5 elements in the filtered output:

```
slideData.slides.filter((slide, index) => {
  if( index < 5 ) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Or, if you're interested in finding a particular contiguous run of elements, as you do in this case, simply use `slice(n, m)` to get elements `n` through `m-1`:

```
slideData.slice(0, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, you want to use `filter` not `map` for an operation that will (potentially) return a subset of an array.

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) always returns the same length array with each item converted based on the function given to `map`.

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a filtered array that contains only the items for which the function given to `filter` returned a truthy value.

So in your case:

```
const slides = slideData.slides.filter((_, i) => i < 5));
```

However, for this particular example, the situation is even simpler since you want a subset of the array based on position. Using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is what you need:

```
const slides = slideData.slides.slice(0, 5); // extract first five items
```